# Drupal based on check box flag, change the textbox text as link or normal text

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

This what I am expecting:

If the user filled the textbox, and if the user checked means, while displaying the content on that time, content should show as a link, if the user is not checked, then it need not to show the link while that content in view mode. See the following image for an illustration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact solution to what you want to do but I believe the [Link Module](http://drupal.org/project/link) will display only text if no url is entered.

You can give users a message saying to leave URL field blank and only enter a TITLE if they want plain text.

---

**UPDATE:**

You don't need to code any hooks. The [CCK Module](http://drupal.org/project/cck) adds fields to content types. The [Link Module](http://drupal.org/project/link) adds link functionality to CCK.

No coding is necessary; this can all be done from the admin panel. If you have no idea what I'm talking about see [this video.](http://learnbythedrop.com/drop/83)

Comment: can u plz tell me hook name, is it possible

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields module does exactly what you are trying to accomplish. You can use the link_field of cck along with the conditional fields module. So based on the value in the check-box you can choose to display it in the node view.